# <textarea> says it supports carriage return new line but it doesn't seem to - google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

First off, here's some screenshots to illustrate my issue.

[image: Entering the song with lyrics into the database.]
[image: How it appears on the display page.]

I'm writing a [crowd-sourced lyric database](http://openlyricbeta.appspot.com/) web app on Google App engine. I have two text input boxes and a text area for the lyrics. However, when I grab the data from the form to add to the database entry, it seems to strip the new lines. Either that, or displaying them is not working properly. [Here's the code](https://github.com/brendan10211/OpenLyric):

```
class addSong(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    song = Song()
    song.title = self.request.get('title')
    song.artist = self.request.get('artist')
    song.data = self.request.get('data')
    song.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

Thanks very much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: HTML doesn't represent newlines unless surrounded by `<pre>` tags. Your need to translate those new line chars to `<br>`  this is really basic html.

Comment: Thanks.. I never really learned HTML completely so I guess I need to focus on it more.